# Initialize ~/.subversion config directory during Vagrant provisioning

Tags: linux, svn, vagrant

Setting up a Linux-based [Vagrant](http://vagrantup.com/) box and configuration, I am looking at the following problem:

During provision stage, I am installing Subversion. I would like, also during the provision stage, to edit the `~/.subversion/servers` file so that it gets necessary proxy settings.

I know how to do that (using `sed`), however there is one catch.

**`~/.subversion` does not exist at this point.**

The directory `~/.subversion` is not actually created until you first call `svn info`, `svn status` or whatever.

So I added to my Vagrantfile...

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "svn info 2>/dev/null"
```

...and the command *does* get executed (with error, since of course there is no working directory to call `info` on)...

```
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: inline script
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.
```

...**but there still is no `~/subversion`.**

I don't quite understand why `svn info`, which does the trick (of setting up `~/.subversion`) works fine when I am logged in to the virtual machine (via `vagrant ssh`), but fails when executed during provisioning as displayed above.

**How can I initialize `~/.subversion` during Vagrant provisioning stage (without actually accessing a real repo)?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "svn info 2>/dev/null"

This line is run *as user `root`*.

Consequently, it does not set up `~vagrant/.subversion`, but `/root/.subversion`.

The solution is to run the line as user `vagrant`:

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "svn info 2>/dev/null", privileged: false
```

Even better, run the command `"svn info 2>/dev/null; true"` -- this gets rid of Vagrant reporting that a provisioning command returned with non-zero exit status.